# Can we get all the areas or area.ui_types available in blender?

Tags: python

I want to get all the areas or `ui_types` available in blender.
Currently I'm manually adding all the available `ui_types` in a list.
`ui_types=["VIEW_3D","OUTLINER",...]`

But I want to get all including new `ui_types` added by other addons like Sverchok addon has it's own `area.ui_type`: `SverchCustomTreeType`.
Is there a way to get all of them without manually  adding it?

Comment: C.window_manager.windows[0].screen.areas[:]... oh sorry, types. docs usually helpull